# detect when user sets alarm Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I am trying to execute an action when the device detects that the alarm is set by the user.

Does anyone know how I can go about doing this in code? Would appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a unified "action" the user performs that will set the alarm. It would probably not even be correct to refer to it as "the alarm", because the alarm is just another application. The user can be using the stock alarm shipping with Android (in the Clock application, I would guess?), the phone manufacturer might have bundled its own alarm app with the phone, or the user might have downloaded a 3rd party alarm application from Android Market.

I would guess that the only thing all those different apps could have in common, is that they in some way could use the [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class to control when the alarm should go off. But I don't think this is something you can listen to (and it is also lots of other apps other than alarm apps that also use the AlarmManager).

Comment: Thanks Nailuj, my code would be trying to listen to the alarm clock, would this be possible somehow? thanks.

Comment: As I said: there is no such thing as _the alarm clock_ - it is just another app. All the large manufacturers (like HTC, Samsung, LG, Motorola etc.) all probably make their own custom clock applications, some use the stock Android clock application, and other users choose to download a 3rd party clock application. So it would be up to the maker of the app to include a way to listen for events from _their_ app, but I don't know if any of them offer such a thing...